# LoadBalancer using Metallb on bare metal RPI cluster not working after installation

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, metallb

I'm fiddling around with my RPI cluster that I've setup using `Kubeadm` and I want to make LoadBalancers able to work on the cluster.
The IPs for the nodes are static and set to the range of `192.168.1.100-192.168.1.103` for the master and worker nodes.

I've installed the Metallb using the offical site docs.

This is my configmap for Metallb:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.2.240-192.168.2.250
```

From what I've understood you're supposed to give the loadbalancers a range outside of the DHCP range of the router? But even changing the addresses range to something like `192.168.1.200-192.168.1.240` doesn't change the results I'm getting.

The DHCP settings for my router.

[image: DHCP settings]

**K8s node info**

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-master      Ready    master   5d15h   v1.17.4   192.168.1.100   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.97-v7l+     docker://19.3.8
k8s-worker-01   Ready    worker   5d15h   v1.17.4   192.168.1.101   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.97-v7+      docker://19.3.8
k8s-worker-02   Ready    worker   4d14h   v1.17.4   192.168.1.102   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.97-v7+      docker://19.3.8
k8s-worker-03   Ready    worker   4d14h   v1.17.4   192.168.1.103   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.97-v7+      docker://19.3.8
```

Then I try to setup a small nginx deployment

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx 
kubectl expose deploy nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
```

Running `kubectl get svc` returns:

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          5d15h
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.96.53.50      <pending>     80:31253/TCP     4s
```

This is where I'm stuck now. I don't seem to be able to get a LoadBalancer to work with this setup and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.

**Metallb output**

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/controller-65895b47d4-q25b8   1/1     Running   0          68m
pod/speaker-bnkpq                 1/1     Running   0          68m
pod/speaker-d56zg                 1/1     Running   0          68m
pod/speaker-h9vpr                 1/1     Running   0          68m
pod/speaker-qsl6f                 1/1     Running   0          68m

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE
daemonset.apps/speaker   4         4         4       4            4           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   68m

NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/controller   1/1     1            1           68m

NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/controller-65895b47d4   1         1         1       68m
```

Comment: Is MetalLB itself actually running?

Comment: @coderanger added output of `metallb get all -n metallb-system`

Comment: can you double-check if your configmap is actually applied? using `kubectl get configmap -n metallb-system`?
also, can you describe the service and add the output? `kubectl describe svc nginx`? Also, metallb controller logs can be helpful: `kubectl -n metallb-system logs controller-65895b47d4-q25b8`

Answer (score 3):

MetalLB layer2 mode doesn't receive broadcast packets unless promiscuous mode is enabled.

Try below

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 promisc
```

Add a Crontab to run each start up so you will not lose this change on restart.

```
    1. sudo crontab -e
    2. Add this line at the end of the file 
         @reboot sudo ifconfig wlan0 promisc
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu 64bit 20.10 on rpi 4. While after executing this command `sudo ifconfig wlan0 promisc`, the metallb is working until rpi is rebooted. How can you persist this command so that it survives the reboot?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me - now I can access the Load Balancer Ingress IP from outside of the cluster. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In my setup with MetalLB, Cilium and HAProxy Ingress Controller I'd to change `externalTrafficPolicy` from `Local` to `Cluster`

```
kubectl --namespace ingress-controller patch svc haproxy-ingress \
 -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Cluster"}}'
```